# Python grouping JSON object using multiple keys

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have this JSON object which has structure as follows (the json object was extracted from pandas dataframe using `to_json(orient="records")`)

```
data = [{'month': 'Jan','date': '18','activity': 'cycling','duration': 3},
        {'month': 'Jan', 'date': '18','activity': 'reading', 'duration': 3.0},
        {'month': 'Jan', 'date': '19', 'activity': 'scripting', 'duration': 19.5},
        {'month': 'Feb','date': '18', 'activity': 'work', 'duration': 22.0 },
        {'month': 'Feb', 'date': '19', 'activity': 'cooking','duration': 0.7},
        {'month': 'March', 'date': '16', 'activity': 'hiking', 'duration': 8.0}]
```

Am trying to group by two fields `month` and `date`
Expected result:

```
data =  [{
            "month": "Jan",
            "details": [{
                "date": "18",
                "effort": [{
                    "activity": "cycling",
                    "duration": 3
                }, {
                    "activity": "reading",
                    "duration": 3.0
                }]
            }, {
                "date": "19",
                "effort": [{
                    "activity": "scripting",
                    "duration": 19.5
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "month": "Feb",
            "details": [{
                "date": "18",
                "effort": [{
                    "activity": "work",
                    "duration": 22.0
                }]
            }, {
                "date": "19",
                "effort": [{
                    "activity": "cooking",
                    "duration": 0.7
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "month": "March",
            "details": [{
                "date": "16",
                "effort": [{
                    "activity": "hiking",
                    "duration": 8.0
                }]
            }]
        }]
```

I tried having the data as python dictionary which is extracted from pandas dataframe using `to_dict(orient="records")`

```
list_ = []

for item in dict_:
    list_.append({"month" : item["month"],
                                "details":
                                [{
                                    "date" : item["date"],
                                    "efforts" : 
                                        [{
                                            "activity" : item["activity"],
                                            "duration": item["duration"]
                                        }]
                                }]
                            })

json.dumps(list_)
```

and the output i got is

```
[{
    "month": "Jan",
    "details": [{
        "date": "18",
        "efforts": [{
            "duration": 3,
            "activity": "cycling"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "month": "Jan",
    "details": [{
        "date": "18",
        "efforts": [{
            "duration": 3.0,
            "activity": "reading"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "month": "Jan",
    "details": [{
        "date": "19",
        "efforts": [{
            "duration": 19.5,
            "activity": "scripting"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "month": "Feb",
    "details": [{
        "date": "18",
        "efforts": [{
            "duration": 22.0,
            "activity": "work"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "month": "Feb",
    "details": [{
        "date": "19",
        "efforts": [{
            "duration": 0.7,
            "activity": "cooking"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "month": "March",
    "details": [{
        "date": "16",
        "efforts": [{
            "duration": 8.0,
            "activity": "hiking"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

am not handling the concatenation of values to the existing fields.

Tried using python as well as java-script, do you guys have any advice or solution to the problem? Thanks

Comment: Please include the code you have tried so we can see what is the problem in the code.

Comment: @Sevanteri update my question with the piece of code that i tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work:

## Code

```
data = [{'month': 'Jan','date': '18','activity': 'cycling','duration': 3},
        {'month': 'Jan', 'date': '18','activity': 'reading', 'duration': 3.0},
        {'month': 'Jan', 'date': '19', 'activity': 'scripting', 'duration': 19.5},
        {'month': 'Feb','date': '18', 'activity': 'work', 'duration': 22.0 },
        {'month': 'Feb', 'date': '19', 'activity': 'cooking','duration': 0.7},
        {'month': 'March', 'date': '16', 'activity': 'hiking', 'duration': 8.0}]

new_data = []
not_found = True
for item in data:
    for month in new_data:
        not_found = True
        if item['month'] == month['month']:
            not_found = False
            for date in month['details']:
                if item['date'] == date['date']:
                    date['effort'].append({'activity':item['activity'], 'duration':item['duration']})
                else:
                    month['details'].append({'date':item['date'], 'effort':[{'activity':item['activity'], 'duration':item['duration']}]})
            break
    if not_found:
        new_data.append({'month':item['month'], 'details':[{'date':item['date'], \
            'effort':[{'activity':item['activity'], 'duration':item['duration']}]}]})

print new_data
```

## Output

```
[{'details': [{'date': '18', 'effort': [{'duration': 3, 'activity': 'cycling'}, {'duration': 3.0, 'activity': 'reading'}]}, {'date': '19', 'effort': [{'duration': 19.5, 'activity': 'scripting'}, {'duration': 19.5, 'activity': 'scripting'}]}], 'month': 'Jan'}, {'details': [{'date': '18', 'effort': [{'duration': 22.0, 'activity': 'work'}]}, {'date': '19', 'effort': [{'duration': 0.7, 'activity': 'cooking'}, {'duration': 0.7, 'activity': 'cooking'}]}], 'month': 'Feb'}, {'details': [{'date': '16', 'effort': [{'duration': 8.0, 'activity': 'hiking'}]}], 'month': 'March'}]
```

Basically just iterate through each entry, first check if the month exists, then if it does, check if the date exists already, and append to the new data accordingly. So if no month exists, you append everything, if no date exists, you append the date details and the new activity. If the date exists too, then you just append the activity

Comment: am facing another issue now. Your answer works for some case and fails for some other case. Please check this [link](https://ideone.com/O9dBPs).

Comment: My code still works, you just changed the input method. instead of using `json.loads(data)`, use `ast.literal_eval(data)` for your input string. remember to do `import ast`

Comment: @dheiberg,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59643833/grouping-the-json-based-on-multiple-keys-using-python
can you help me in solving this

Comment: @DineshkarthikRaveendran, could you help me as well ?

Answer (score 0):

A generic function to group JSON. You must pass field to group and key array name for groups

```
def groupBy(vetor, campos, pos):
    if(pos >= len(campos)):
      return vetor
    gmx = campos[pos]
    agrupado = gmx["field"]
    kx = gmx["gbkey"]
    tam = len(campos)
    agrupados = {}
    saida = {}
    retorno = []    
    for l in vetor:
        lmf = {}
        for k, s in l.items():
            val_agrupado = l[agrupado]             
            if not (val_agrupado in agrupados):
                agrupados[val_agrupado] = []
            if agrupado != k:
              lmf[k] = s
        agrupados[val_agrupado].append(lmf)              
    for l in agrupados:
        agrup = agrupados[l]
        if(len(campos) > 1):            
            agrup = groupBy(agrup, campos, pos + 1)
        saida = {}
        saida[agrupado] = l
        saida[kx] = agrup
        retorno.append(saida)
    return retorno
    
data = [{'month': 'Jan','date': '18','activity': 'cycling','duration': 3},
        {'month': 'Jan', 'date': '18','activity': 'reading', 'duration': 3.0},
        {'month': 'Jan', 'date': '19', 'activity': 'scripting', 'duration': 19.5},
        {'month': 'Feb','date': '18', 'activity': 'work', 'duration': 22.0 },
        {'month': 'Feb', 'date': '19', 'activity': 'cooking','duration': 0.7},
        {'month': 'March', 'date': '16', 'activity': 'hiking', 'duration': 8.0}]
print(groupBy(data, [{'field':'month', 'gbkey': 'details'}, {'field':'date', 'gbkey': 'effort'}], 0))
```

It will produces something like

```
[
   {
      "month":"Jan",
      "details":[
         {
            "date":"18",
            "effort":[
               {
                  "activity":"cycling",
                  "duration":3
               },
               {
                  "activity":"reading",
                  "duration":3.0
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "date":"19",
            "effort":[
               {
                  "activity":"scripting",
                  "duration":19.5
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "month":"Feb",
      "details":[
         {
            "date":"18",
            "effort":[
               {
                  "activity":"work",
                  "duration":22.0
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "date":"19",
            "effort":[
               {
                  "activity":"cooking",
                  "duration":0.7
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "month":"March",
      "details":[
         {
            "date":"16",
            "effort":[
               {
                  "activity":"hiking",
                  "duration":8.0
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Have you really posted code with hispanic variable names on english site?